# Polygon intersection using turf js

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-draw, turf

I have given this code for intersection:

```
function intersectPolyByPolyFC(poly,fcPoly){
        var fgp=[];//variable for feature group
        var bbPoly=turf.bboxPolygon(turf.bbox(poly));//polygon representation of the bounding box of a reference polygon
        for(var i=0;i<fcPoly.features.length;i++){//loop through the feature collection of polygons
            var bb=turf.bboxPolygon(turf.bbox(fcPoly.features[i]));//variable bb represents each polygon for feature collection
            if(turf.intersect(bbPoly,bb)){//condition to check if the two bounding boxes intersect
                var int= turf.intersect(poly,fcPoly.features[i]);
                if(int){
                    int.properties=fcPoly.features[i].properties;
                    fgp.push(int);
                }
            }
        }
        return turf.featureCollection(fgp);
    }
```

and the function definition I have given as

```
var bufline=turf.buffer(line,0.05,{units:"kilometers"});
var intBUOWL= intersectPolyByPolyFC(bufline, lyrBUOWL.toGeoJSON());
L.geoJSON(intBUOWL,{style:{color:'red',weight:5}}).addTo(mymap);
```

When I am drawing a line over a polygon for intersection I am getting this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at Object.t.collect (turf.min.js:1)
    at summarizePointsByLine (buffer.html:440)
    at NewClass.<anonymous> (buffer.html:155)
    at NewClass.fire (Events.js:190)
    at NewClass._fireCreatedEvent (leaflet.draw.js:8)
    at NewClass._fireCreatedEvent (leaflet.draw.js:8)
    at NewClass.completeShape (leaflet.draw.js:8)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.handler (DomEvent.js:92)
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: The error happens in a function you did not include. What is `summarizePointsByLine` and what is in line 440 of that HTML file?

Comment: There is not enough of code to find out what and why it goes wrong. Please edit your question and add more of relevant code.

Comment: summarizepointsByLine function actually tells the details of the points that are intersected by a drawn line through leaflet draw plugin

Comment: is there any problem with my leaflet draw plugin coz as soon as i draw the line over the polygon the above error is displayed over the screen

Comment: line is the object passed to the function where line is the drawn line over the polygons with leaflet draw plugin

Comment: As commented before, there is not enough of code to find out what and why it goes wrong. Please edit your question and add more of relevant code.

Comment: ok sir i will provide more of the code